# How to achieve unattended deployments with ASP.NET website, as opposed to web apps?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, continuous-deployment, vs-web-site-project

With the lack of web.config transform support in ASP.NET web site projects, as opposed to web app projects, what's the best practice to achieve unattended deployments?

It seems to me that without web.config transform support, there will always need to be a manual intervention step if the web.config changes and the site is deployed to a new environment (like QA, staging, or production). I was looking for a way to run the transforms myself but that doesn't seem to be exposed.

How have other's solved this?

Answer (score 0):

We never include web.configs in our normal deployment process, they are excluded, the staging and production web.configs are edited manually and don't usually change that much.

If you need to deploy a large number of sites and want to deploy the web.config files, you can still write your own transforms, they are just XML and easy to manipulate with PowerShell.